# LibUsbDotNet returns garbage

Tags: c#, mono, usb, linux-device-driver, libusb

I wrote an application to read a magnetic card-reader using a usb connection. I used libusbdotnet, because it communicates directly with libusb 1.xx on linux.

When I pull the card through, I get a lot of what I believe is binary data that doesn't match the data I get when I'm using the pc hid driver. The pc sees the card-reader as a keyboard device.

How can I fix or debug this? I tested it on my windows system, but I receive the same results.

Comment: Can you add the code for your application?

Comment: For all guys ending up here: I assume the binary data consists of HID commands. HID does not send characters directly through the wire. You have to process the HID data (normally 8 bytes at a time) to get the characters typed. This is what the default HID driver normally does for you without you worrying about that stuff. Maybe all you ned to do is read up how HID works.